# How do I Initialize C code while only using words

Tags: c, initialization

how do i Initialize my code if all im using are words and no numbers?

I have been trying to just use char * but it is saying that its still not initialized

```
char *Carson;


printf("Enter a name:\n");
scanf("%s",Name);

printf("%s Hello Carson\n", Carson);
```

Comment: Is this a puzzle? I'm thinking of a weird solution.

Comment: I'm not sure how one goes about "initializing code" in general. Also, use `fgets`, not `scanf`.

Answer (score 1):

You *either* have to allocate memory dynamically and assign it to `Carson` (see e.g. [`malloc?](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/malloc) ), *or* make it an array. There's no way around it. And for that, the code must contain a number. The number *could* be input from the user though, so you won't have any actual numbers in the source.

Remember that in C all strings need an extra terminator character (added automatically by `scanf`) so remember to add space for it.

Answer (score 1):

A solution without any number, I don't think this must be used for practical applications, just a hack

```
char Carson[sizeof(long long) * sizeof(long long)];
printf("Size = %d\n", sizeof Carson);
printf("Enter a name:\n");
scanf("%s",Carson);
printf("%s Hello Carson\n", Carson);
```

In my system it create a char array of 64 bytes = 8 * 8, the size of `long long` in most systems is 8 bytes although it's size depends on your compiler and operating system

Answer (score 0):

you might like to initialize `Carson` like this:

`char *Carson = malloc(sizeof(char)*200);/* for 200 characters */`

Don't forget to add `\0` terminator and also, donot forget to `free` it once you are done using it.

Comment: @rendon I am not sure I understand that

Comment: Maybe it's me who don't understand...I think the question asks for a solution where no numbers appears.

Answer (score 0):

In order to initialize variables in **C** you need to use constants values, that is, expressions whose value can be known at compile time.
For integer or float types you can use mathematical formulas involving only constant operands, thus you can obtain still a constant value that can be used in a initiaiization.

What you call "words" have been called better "strings".
In **C** you are able to use strings that are constant at compile time, also called "string literals".
A string literal has to be indicated surrounded by quotes, like these examples:

```
"Hello world!"  
"Peter & John"
"user@gmail.com"
```

and so on.

There are some rules that you need to remember: some special characters have "escape sequences" to be used inside a string literal.

Now you can use that string literals in order to initialize a `char*` variable:

```
 char *name = "Mr. Smith";
 char *city = "Amsterdam";
```

The result of the initialization gives a **C string** style, that is, an array of char object, whose length is the amount of quoted characters in the string literal, plus 1, because a null character is added at the end. Thus, in memory you have:

```
 char *city ----> |A|m|s|t|e|r|d|a|m|\0|
```

Thus, city points to an array of 10 chars.
The last character, `\0`, means "null character", whose ASCII code is 0. Since it corresponds to a non-printable character, it has to be indicated with the escape sequence `\0`.

For more information, take a look on these websites:

- [Escape sequences in C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C)
- [Storage of string literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0h227906.aspx)

If you initialize a pointer to char object to a string literal, the compiler reserves memory automatically for you, son you don't need any `malloc()` at all.
However, you cannot modify the characters of such a string.

If you are interested in modify the characters, you can use better un array of char object:

```
 char name[30] = "Schwarzenegger";
```

The array reserves 30 chars for the string literal "Schwarzenegger".
Only the first 14 are used for the string, plus 1 holding the null character attached at the end.
The rest of chars of the array have dummy information, but there is no problem because they are not printed.  (The standard library functions always stop processing the string when they encounter a null character).

---

**EDITED** More information.

About your particular error message: "lack of initialization", the problem is that in the definition of the pointer to char object:

```
 char *name;
```

you only have a "pointer to" an undefined block of memory.
You have to specify the array of char that `name` will be point to.

If you initialize with a string literal, there is not any problem, because the address of the string literal is passed to `name`.

But, since you are planning to use `name` for data input by means of `scanf()`, you have to allocate memory enough. You can do that other users have explained yet in their answers, that is, by using `malloc()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is need to do changes in your code,

char *Carson = NULL;
Carson = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*256);

printf("Enter a name:\n");
scanf("%s",Carson );

printf("%s Hello Carson\n", Carson);

in place of 256 u can use whatever value you want.
let me know if it works.